# Why are the off-topic flags buried under "It should be closed for another reason..."?

Tags: support, flags, user-interface

I imagine that off topic flags are the most common kind by far. Why do users without the close vote privilege need to click through two layers of menus to get to them? I would never have guessed that "another reason" contained "off topic" without clicking through and looking.

Comment: So... where exactly *would* you expect them to appear in that dialog if not in the "it should be closed" subdialog?

Comment: @animuson I'd expect them to appear in the "it should be closed," not "it should be closed for *another reason*." "Another reason" suggests to me that this is some obscure edge case that I'll rarely need to worry about, rather than (what I assume is) the overwhelmingly most common case.

Comment: @animuson In particular, I'd expect "off topic" to be in the first list of things that I see, with "hate speech," "spam," etc underneath "another reason." This gives me a more severe list of flags to escalate to if I feel like the common ones aren't applicable, but it puts the most pertinent information in front of me right away.

Comment: Another reason means a reason that is not already in the list presented to you.

Comment: @animuson That's like posting a classified ad for a software engineer that goes in to two pages of detail about how to operate the coffee machine at the office, followed by "Other duties include writing code." Is it semantically correct to say that operating the coffee pot is one duty, and writing code is "another duty?" Yes. Does it accurately portray the responsibilities of the position? Probably not.

Comment: That is probably the worst analogy I have ever read.

Comment: @animuson Thanks. My point is that "another reason" is an accurate way to describe it, but it doesn't convey that "this is almost certainly the reason you clicked that 'flag' button."

Comment: Totally agree, I had searched for the same thing and was very annoyed that it was under other.

Comment: Why is the off-topic close reason so vitally important that it needs to be in the top-level list? That list is meant to be the most important flags, yet you're essentially calling all of those "operating a coffee machine" and saying that off-topic is more important than all of them. Why?

Comment: @animuson As I said in the comment below -- "Spam, hate speech, etc are certainly more serious than off-topic questions, but I'd be shocked if they were anywhere near as common." The common case should be simple. I'm working under the assumption that most bad posts on SO are from people who are reasonably well-intentioned but unaware of how the community works, rather than from actively malicious things like spam, hate speech, etc. I could be wrong.

Comment: Welp, here's my friendly mockup: http://jsfiddle.net/33xr8so0/

Comment: FWIW, "not an answer" is the most common flag by a huuuuuge margin - in the past 30 days, there have been nearly double the number of NAA flags as OT flags. Everyone *remembers* the off-topic questions, but they're not nearly as numerous as some other common issues.

Comment: I think another good data-point re: the phrasing of "closed for another reason" is the fact that higher-rep users are confronted with two buttons: "flag," of course, and "close." Because *that* aspect of the UI seems to consider those to be two distinct acts, it seems reasonable that the flag dialog could get away with just "it should be closed." I don't think those reasons need to be top-level, in fact I don't think they should be for the same reason, but the phrasing could be slightly altered to be more clear and consistent with the usage: we're training new users about the close dialog.

Comment: On the Android app, I've sometimes accidentally tapped the "offensive" option instead of the "closed for another reason", because it initially looks like "off-topic". On the app, once you choose an option, it gets submitted immediately instead of having to click another button to confirm it.

Comment: Flag is to dealing with something more severe than off-topic, I believe. You can use the [close](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270253/why-are-the-off-topic-flags-buried-under-it-should-be-closed-for-another-reason?cb=1#) button for the off-topic instead?

Comment: @Bolu Not at <3k rep -- the users who are most likely to be confused.

Comment: Go over to stackapps and search for "Always Be Closing"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many off-topic reasons (and other closing reasons), so it would be difficult to display them all together in the front page.

I believe the reason they are nested under a unique bullet is to also display other equal important issues  like, spam, hate speech and duplicates.

Maybe, that text could be improved for disambiguation with a complement like the following:

> It should be closed for another reason (e.g., off-topic, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, etc.)

Comment: I think that would be sensible. Spam, hate speech, etc are certainly more serious than off-topic questions, but I'd be shocked if they were anywhere near as common.

Comment: I thought the idea was only to raise the "off-topic" *subdialog* to top level of the flag dialog; not each off-topic reason.

Comment: @npostavs, that could work too. I tried to explain why it's not in the front page (maybe off-topic and other closing reasons are equally important) and tried to provide an alternative (which was to add a complement, after 'another option').

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>[image: Flag dialog]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: Flag To close Dialog]</kbd>

Comment: WHERE IS THE OFF TOPIC FLAGS?!?! OH, I have to scroll, ugh!

Comment: @Braiam If your you're using a 720x480 screen on a non-mobile, sure.

Comment: Hmm, I have a sufficiently large screen and I still don't see any off-topic flags. Part of the problem is that you've used the Meta close reasons as a template, which are rather different from those used on the main site.

Answer (score -8):

Because the default state of questions is to be open. Both Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky have written about an often overlooked aspect of UI design. 
*You should make it harder to do things you don't want your users to do.*

By putting the close reasons behind several clicks, instead of one, you are given time to assess whether or not you should really be casting that close vote. I'm just an average Joe user, but I'm willing to bet this is by design.

Comment: So obviously it should be easier to flag everything as offensive…

Comment: @bjb568 I might be wrong, but I suspect the idea is that if someone opens the flag dialog with the intent of marking something as offensive, they probably have a good reason (they see something offensive). However, if they're opening it to close it as "Unclear what you're asking," for example, that could be a little more subjective. Obviously we want new users to have that ability to contribute, but we also want them to carefully consider the definitions of each close reason, and they're discouraged to make quick decisions before growing quite familiar with each reason and its application.

Comment: I think the wording could be adjusted, as has been mentioned, because "another reason" can be a tad confusing, but I am starting to see the value of the separation.

Comment: With this logic, we should make it a lot easier to close questions—we *want* poor quality questions to be closed. Certainly Jeff felt this way when designing the closure feature; I'm not sure about Joel.

Comment: @bjb568 maybe back when this was designed the main problem was indeed offensive questions and not low quality ones, but now it's definitely the opposite and it should be much easier to flag low quality stuff.

Comment: In defense of my answer, OP did not ask if it ***should*** be this way. He asked ***why*** it is this way. When it was designed, there wasn't an overwhelming deluge of questions to be closed.